# Two Recyclerview one in Bottom Sheet Layout not showing data in Coordinate Layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

Hey Everyone I have two recyclerviews out of which one is in **bottom sheet**. The top one is working fine but bottom one is not showing anything. and there is no error displaying in logcat as well. 
This is my **MainActivity.Class**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.app.adapter.CardViewDataAdapter;
import com.example.app.adapter.UserListAdapter;
import com.example.app.beans.ItemsBean;
import com.example.app.classes.UserSelectedItems;
import com.example.app.database.DBHelper;
import com.example.app.utils.CommonUtilities;
import com.example.app.utils.Constants;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView, selected_recyclerview;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    UserListAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<String> selected_items= new ArrayList<>();
    View bottomSheet;
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior;

    private List<ItemsBean> itemList;
    String[] items= new String[]{"Sugar", "Tea", "Coffee", "Milk", "Bread", "Butter", "Jeera", "Egg", "Buiscuit", "JAM", "Maggi",
    "Wheat", "Lentils", "Shampoo","Soap", "oil", "Hair Spray", "Coconut", "Cream", "Curd", "Cheese"};

    String[] item_ids= new String[]{"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114",
    "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121"};

    private Button btnSelection;
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        btnSelection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        selected_recyclerview= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
            }
        });
        dbHelper= CommonUtilities.getDBObject(this);
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            ItemsBean bean= new ItemsBean();
            bean.setItemId(item_ids[i]);
            bean.setItemName(items[i]);
            bean.setItemStatus(1);
            itemList.add(bean);
            ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
            values.put(Constants.ITEM_ID,item_ids[i]);
            values.put(Constants.ITEM_NAME, items[i]);
            values.put(Constants.ITEM_STATUS,1);
            dbHelper.insertContentVals(Constants.MASTER_ITEM_TABLE, values);

        }

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Grocery List");

        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(itemList);

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = "";
                List<ItemsBean> stList = ((CardViewDataAdapter) mAdapter)
                        .getStudentist();

                for (int i = 0; i < stList.size(); i++) {
                    ItemsBean singleStudent = stList.get(i);
                    if (singleStudent.isSelected() == true) {
                        selected_items.add(singleStudent.getItemName().toString());
                        data = data + "\n" + singleStudent.getItemName().toString();
                        /*
                         * Toast.makeText( CardViewActivity.this, " " +
                         * singleStudent.getName() + " " +
                         * singleStudent.getEmailId() + " " +
                         * singleStudent.isSelected(),
                         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         */
                    }

                }

                selected_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                selected_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

                adapter = new UserListAdapter(MainActivity.this, selected_items);
                selected_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                Log.e("size", "size=" + selected_items.size());
                /*Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserSelectedItems.class);
                i.putStringArrayListExtra("selected", (ArrayList<String>) selected_items);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Selected Students: \n" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Here is my **xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#a3b1ef"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#00796B"
            android:text="Show Selected"
            android:textColor="@color/TextPrimaryColor" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#fff" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/proceed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is user_list_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/col444"
        android:text="Sugar"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/brand"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/col444"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_name"
        ></Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/col444"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/brand"
        ></Spinner>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:hint="Qty."
        android:textColor="@color/col444"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is **UserItem Adapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.app.R;
import com.example.app.beans.SelectedBean;
import com.example.app.classes.UserSelectedItems;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by me on 9/22/2016.
 */
public class UserListAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.UserViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<String> data;
    String[] brands= new String[]{
            "Select Brand","Brand One", "Brand Two", "Brand Three", "Brand Four"
    };
    String[] units= new String[]{"Select Unit", "Kg", "Gms", "Lbs", "Pieces"};


    public UserListAdapter(Context context, List<String> data){
       this.context= context;
       this.data= data;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.user_list_row, null);
        // create ViewHolder
        UserViewHolder viewHolder = new UserViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemName.setText(data.get(position));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, brands);
        holder.brand.setAdapter(adapter);
        ArrayAdapter<String> madapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, units);
        holder.unit.setAdapter(madapter);
       /* holder.unit.setSelection(0);
        holder.brand.setSelection(0);*/
        final SelectedBean bean= new SelectedBean();
        bean.setItemName(data.get(position));
        holder.unit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position!=0){
                    bean.setUnitName(units[position]);
                    bean.setUnitSelectedPos(position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
               /* if(DetailActivity.list!=null && DetailActivity.list.size()>0) {
                    holder.brand.setSelection(DetailActivity.list.get(position).getBrandSelectedPos());
                    holder.unit.setSelection(DetailActivity.list.get(position).getUnitSelectedPos());
                }*/
            }
        });
        holder.brand.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bean.setBrandName(brands[position]);
                bean.setBrandSelectedPos(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                bean.setQuantity(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        holder.brand.setSelection(bean.getBrandSelectedPos());
        holder.unit.setSelection(bean.getUnitSelectedPos());
        Log.e("size", "= "+  UserSelectedItems.list.size());

        UserSelectedItems.list.add(bean);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView itemName;
        EditText quantity;
        Spinner brand, unit;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemName= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            quantity= (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            brand= (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand);
            unit= (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what should I do to show data in recyclerview in **bottom sheet layout**. There is a button at the bottom on click of which the bottom sheet expands like below. 
[image: Output]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show UserListAdapter and raw_list_item xml

Comment: @AlexChengalan Its done please check

Answer (score 0):

Add this below `selected_items.add(singleStudent.getItemName().toString());` inside MainActivity,

```
int position = selected_item.size() - 1; 
adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
```

and if you wanna scroll to newly added item then add this as well,

```
selected_recyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: caused null pointer exception as I have to initialize the adapter later after the for loop @Sushant

Comment: Initialize the adapter above loop then :P cause your view won't be updated unless you notify adapter about it

Comment: I cant initialize it before as I have to pass data in it.. And with my code I am able to receive data in adapter class as I have set logs there. But view is not showing dont know why

Comment: Is it printing the error log inside **onBindViewHolder** of **UserListAdapter**?

Comment: Try adding `android:weightSum="1"` inside **LinearLayout** of **user_list_row** and let me know if it works

Comment: Run me through your idea quickly cause something doesn't seem to fit the bill.

Comment: I want to select items from recyclerview and then want to take more info for selected items in bottom layout.

Comment: Then you don't need to go through all the rigmarole and check boolean values for selected items. You can use setOnCheckedChangeListener of other RecyclerView and add items to bottom RecyclerView if isChecked is true :P

Comment: bottom recyclerview is in bottom sheet which is taking input as i menioned values are receiving but not showing

Comment: Yeah I understand that but it'll be easier if you add the item as soon as you click on checkbox. It'll add item to bottom RecyclerView if isChecked true otherwise it won't.Like if you click on Sugar, it'll directly add Sugar|Select Brand|Select Unit|Qty to bottom view. If you click on any other item as well,it'll be added next to Sugar :P

Comment: But i want once the bottom sheet is opened user should not interact with upper list else he ll tick untick the choices.. Can you code for what you are saying ?

Comment: Yeah I can try but you'll need to give me a day or two :P

Comment: I have time till tommorrow if you can help then it would be good

Comment: sure i ll wait for your response

Comment: Hey I'm done with the code so can you give me your email id? I'd rather mail the project than posting here :P

Comment: its preetika.kaur12@gmail.com

Comment: I've mailed you just now so have a look and let me know

Comment: You helpeda lot but your code some how did not give result what I need. I made modifications in my code and its working well now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

set in parent view

```
android:weightSum="1"
```